# How to include html supporting files to display Html File in web browser (Visual Basic 2013)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, webbrowser-control

I have a local HTML file named `test.html` to be displayed into web browser control. I have included it in project, also I have set its Properties, `Build Action` to `Content`, and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always`.

But the problem is with its supporting files (css, js etc). I have kept them all into a folder named `html_assets`, included it in project. This folder contains many supporting files (to be more clear, it contains tinymce editor javascript plugin, which is a group of more than 50-70 files).

**How can I include this whole folder into my app's installation path (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), so that links into my html file `test.html` are not broken?**

If somehow `Resourses` is used to include the folder, then how will the `test.html` will call its supporting .js, .css files?

I am using Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2013.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve this with Post build event scripts - they allow you to do actions after the compile and there are expansions you can use that will specify the bin path etc...